# Can't login to Dundas Dashboard in Chrome, but in Internet Explorer I can

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, dundas

Can anyone help me figure out why I can't log in to Dundas dashboard if I use Google Chrome, but if I use Internet Explorer I can?

My Dundas Dashboard is v3.0, and my Chrome is Version 45.0.2454.93 B.

Answer (score 0):

I believe Chrome is no longer supporting Silverlight, so that's likely the issue.

See https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3058254 and https://superuser.com/a/914958/105402.

Comment: thank for the answer, but I would think to use lower version of google chrome, I think this can give solution, but still find google chrome old version doesn't exist anymore.